# How to give ranking for two different variables?

Tags: ranks

I have two variables: one is "Due amount" and another one is "Overdue days".

How to rank these variables? Few customers have big amounts but they will delay the payment by a few days only, so there is no problem with them because they will however pay soon.

On the other hand, few customers have less amounts but they will delay a lot, but since the amount is less, there is less point following up with them.

I need to identify a method to rank these two variables so that I can follow up with the customers where they have huge amount and they delay a lot.

Below is an example:

```
Overdue Days    Amount  Rank(Days)  Rank(Amount)
2               100000  10           1
59              42692   3            2
89              32591   2            5
28              22283   4            6
5               38865   9            3
22              46      6            9
121             10      1            10
27              9100    5            8
21              33307   7            4
9               17609   8            7
```

I know this is simple but I could not get a good method.

Comment: It is not clear what the question is here. Your comments about what kinds of values you have in practice seem independent of any question of how to assign ranks. The ranks are the ranks, depending on conventions about whether you assign ranks lowest to highest or highest to lowest and what you do about ties. If the problem is that the ranks don't capture what you want, then don't use them; use the values instead.

Comment: You may need to define a problem metric, e.g. overdue days $\times$ amount due.